# 2 forms, 1 page - WebMatrix/Razor

Tags: sql, post, razor, http-post, webmatrix

i want to have 2 forms on one page, an each one updates different data in my database. How do i get one Submit Button to run one UPDATE query, and the other form to run another?

I've created a test page, but i'm having no luck. I'm guessing i need to name each form, and then create 2 if(ispost) statements for each one?

Here's what i have so far:

```
@{
Layout = "~/_template1.cshtml";
Page.Title = "Add Property";

var db = Database.Open("StayInFlorida");

var propertyinfo = "SELECT * FROM PropertyInfo WHERE PropertyID='8'";
var propinfo = db.QuerySingle(propertyinfo);

if (IsPost){
    var form1 = "UPDATE PropertyInfo SET PropertyName = @0, PropertyWebSite = @1 WHERE PropertyID='8'";
    db.Execute(form1, Request["PropertyName"], Request["PropertyWebsite"]);
}
if (IsPost){
    var form2 = "UPDATE PropertyInfo SET NumBedrooms = @0, NumBathrooms = @1 WHERE PropertyID='8'";
    db.Execute(form2, Request["NumBedrooms"], Request["NumBathrooms"]);
}
}

<hr>
<div class="tabbable">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Tab1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">tab2</a></li>
</ul>

<!--Tab Content-->
<div class="tab-content">

<div id="tab1" class="tab-pane active">
<form method="post" action="">
<fieldset>
<label>Property Name:</label>
<input class="input-xlarge" type="text" name="PropertyName" placeholder=".input-xlarge" value="@propinfo.PropertyName">
<br>
<label>Property Website:</label>
<input class="input-xlarge" type="text" name="PropertyWebsite" placeholder=".input-xlarge" value="@propinfo.PropertyWebsite">
<br>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Update</button>
</fieldset>
</form>
</div>

<div id="tab2" class="tab-pane">
<form method="post" action="">
<fieldset>
<label>Number of Bedrooms:</label>
<input class="input-xlarge" type="text" name="NumBedrooms" placeholder=".input-xlarge" value="@propinfo.NumBedrooms">
<br>
<label>Number of Bathrooms:</label>
<input class="input-xlarge" type="text" name="NumBathrooms" placeholder=".input-xlarge" value="@propinfo.NumBathrooms">
<br>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Update</button>
</fieldset>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<hr>
```

Thanks, Gavin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a name attribute to each button along with a value e.g.:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="Action" value="Update1">Update</button>
```

Then check in the server code which one was clicked:

```
if (Request["Action"] == "Update1"){
    //button 1 was clicked
}
```

Comment: should each button have a unique name and value for each form?

Comment: ignore that last comment, works a treat, thanks so much again